# Use bootstrap in jquery datatable without defaults property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

i need some help to improve the look of my datatable. I am using jquery datatable and facing to styling it. i would like to change the appearence of my datatable by using bootstrap (specialy pagination styling). I have read some ways from internet and having this example of datatable's web site (https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html). When i have tried to implement this with all the required css and js files, i always get this error:
 javaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'defaults' of undefined or null reference. When i have a look of the page, it seems that the datatable has implemented or have tried to implement the defaults setting. I would like to know how could i override these defaults setting to implement this pagination styling.

Comment: Please add code here u have used to add data table on your html page.

Answer (score 0):

It' very easy to customizing datatable to bootstrap

you just need add the below given js and css

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plugins/e9421181788/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plugins/e9421181788/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.1/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.1/css/dataTables.fixedHeader.css">
```

Demo for boostrap datatable:
http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/xF8hZ/811/

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @El camerounian i hope this what you want, if you have any difficulty let me know. Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you @Dipak Thoke, i have tried this, but i still having some problem with my table: there are two visible header for the table, the label search and it textbox, the label for the number of records per page and it dropdown list are in the same place with one above the other. pagination and showing 5 of 10 on 45 are also one above the others. I also don't get pagination which look like your(my pagination is poorly designed). I have put my table in a div and donesn't know if it is this content which allows to obtain these thing. UI of the tables don't have a rounded corner as for your table

Comment: @El camerounian can you add html code to your above question so that i can answer perfectly.

Comment: this is the link (http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/xF8hZ/811/#&togetherjs=c7SzIh5JJC), data are fetched from the controller with ajax and by clicking the first column, you can get specific detail from a partial view

Comment: they are not two headers  one  them is footer if want to remove  footer have remove <tfoot> </tfoot> tag from html .please show me your html code here.

Comment: i don't have your pagination